# How to use JPA (Java Persistance API) with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, jpa

I know how to use JPA with Oracle and derby DBMSs, but is it possible to use MySQL DBMS with the Java Persistence API ? If so, how ?

Comment: Of course ... this is one of the main advantages of an ORM.

Comment: read a JPA tutorial and it will explain how you set your JDBC connection, and it ought to be obvious that you can use it with ANY JDBC supported database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use MySQL and Java Persistence API.

JPA is not only restricted to Oracle or derby. For example, Netbeans 8 let you use JPA with MySQL. It has everything built in for that functionality such as the MySQL JDBC connector and a JPA implementation called EclipseLink.

If you want to test it yourself, take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/SettingUpJPA/SettingUpJPA.htm). Although it is referring to derby DBMS, the steps are similiar for MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You may use heavyweight J2EE servers, Jetty/Tomcat servlet engines or standalone Java apps to run JPA stack. Should not matter which jdbc driver being used.

I always use MariaDB(read: MySQL) in  my [ScopedEntityManager project](https://github.com/Murmur/ScopedEntityManager) fine, also have installed on IBM-WAS web server using MSSQL jdbc driver. Download [MariaDB Connector/J](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-mariadb-connector-j/) and [MySQL Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-versions.html) packages. You may put both jdbc files to a same application and use connection string to identify which one of the driver use.

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbname?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8`

Answer (score 0):

Like most JPA implementations, using the proper [JDBC adapter](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). What's your JPA implementation? EclipseLink?

Edit: You need to have access to a MySQL database, which is trivial to setup.